# Method comparison fails in Neko but works on JavaScript

Tags: html, if-statement, haxe, neko

I have a pretty "simple" problem.

```
class Main {
    public static function main()
        new Main();

    public function new() {
        var a = callbackFunc;
        var b = callbackFunc;

        if (a == b)
            trace("success");
        else
            trace("Failed");
    }

    private function callbackFunc():Void {}
}
```

When compiled to the JavaScript target everything is fine... in Neko it traces "Failed"... Didn't find anything useful in the net that might explain the Problem... Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Reflect.compareMethods()`](http://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html?#compareMethods) - this should work on all targets:

```
if (Reflect.compareMethods(a, b))
    trace("success");
else    
    trace("Failed");
```

The comparison operator is not specified to always work on functions, it depends on the target.

Comment: The equality operator also depends on the type of function: on Neko, it can handle static functions just fine.  But it's best to use the `Reflect`-ion API and abstract over these target differences.